# What date should one list for an award? Should it be the date of notification or the date of presentation?

Tags: background-check

A couple of months ago, I was informed that I won a major honor in my field. However, the honor is not being publicly presented until sometime in the next 6 weeks. Obviously I am not listing it on my LinkedIn or anything until then, but what is the correct date for listing it after the fact?

Answer (score 4):

I'd say the date of presentation or public notice.

However, you probably don't need to be any more specific than giving the year you received the award. That and the name of the award (and the awarding body) should be more than sufficient for a background check.

Comment: The correct date is the date it was awarded, but agree the best thing to do is list the year and not a specific date (if you can).